# Translucent nav bar with background image behind: css, no javascript

Tags: html, css

Bit of a newbie, but trying to do something i thought would be quite simple; i'd like a full screen background image with no margins, that scales to screen size (i'm using background: cover; at the moment) but I'd like to put a translucent nav bar over the top of the image right at the top, containing a horizontal menu.

So far, I have the nav bar, but the image is sitting either above the nav bar, or underneath it, instead of directly on top. What's the best way of doing this, is it z-index values, or is there something easy i should be doing to place one div (.nav) over another (.background-img)?

any help much appreciated, sorry if this is a bit vague but i am a total newcomer to html & css!!

Comment: Are you using `position: fixed` for background div and nav div?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please always include your current code within your question. Otherwise we won't be able to help and the question is likely to become closed. Use the **edit** button under your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Position: fixed; totally sorted it!! Thanks so much for helping me out - and thanks for advice guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `position:fixed;` if you're not already. Do something like this:

```
div.background-img {
    background-image: url('background.png');
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-size:cover;
}
div.nav {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    padding: 16px;
}
```

See a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MBZA2/1/)